# Python unicode dictornary to string from twitch stream

Tags: python, unicode, twitch

I'm trying to decode a twitch api answer in python.

```
import urllib2
import json


url  = 'http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=kungentv'

result =json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(url, timeout = 100).read().decode('utf-8'))
print result
```

If i run this i get this:

```
[{u'broadcast_part': 6, u'featured': True, u'channel_subscription': True, u'embed_count': 0, u'id': u'9602378624', u'category': u'gaming', u'title': u'5x Legend - Playing the TOP DECKS from DECK WARS to Legendary! Handlock, Miracle and Shaman. (Never played Shaman EVUR)', u'video_height': 1080, u'site_count': 0, u'embed_enabled': False, u'channel': {u'category': u'gaming', u'status': u'5x Legend - Playing the TOP DECKS from DECK WARS to Legendary! Handlock, Miracle and Shaman. (Never played Shaman EVUR)', u'views_count': 56403101, u'subcategory': None, u'language': u'en', u'title': u'kungentv', u'screen_cap_url_huge': u'http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews/live_user_kungentv-630x473.jpg', u'producer': True, u'tags': None, u'subcategory_title': u'', u'category_title': u'', u'screen_cap_url_large': u'http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews/live_user_kungentv-320x240.jpg', u'mature': None, u'screen_cap_url_small': u'http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews/live_user_kungentv-70x53.jpg', u'screen_cap_url_medium': u'http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews/live_user_kungentv-150x113.jpg', u'timezone': u'Europe/Stockholm', u'login': u'kungentv', u'channel_url': u'http://www.justin.tv/kungentv', u'id': 30383713, u'meta_game': u'Hearthstone: Heroes of Warcraft'}, u'up_time': u'Mon May 19 00:34:43 2014', u'meta_game': u'Hearthstone: Heroes of Warcraft', u'format': u'live', u'stream_type': u'live', u'channel_count': 3671, u'abuse_reported': False, u'video_width': 1920, u'geo': u'SE', u'name': u'live_user_kungentv', u'language': u'en', u'stream_count': 0, u'video_bitrate': 3665.328125, u'broadcaster': u'obs', u'channel_view_count': 0}]
```

How do i decode this so I can use it a normal string dictionary.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to decode anything; Python will encode and decode string values as needed for you.

Demo:

```
>>> result = [{u'broadcast_part': 6, u'featured': True, u'channel_subscription': True, u'embed_count': 0, u'id': u'9602378624', u'category': u'gaming', u'title': u'5x Legend - Playing the TOP DECKS from DECK WARS to Legendary! Handlock, Miracle and Shaman. (Never played Shaman EVUR)', u'video_height': 1080, u'site_count': 0, u'embed_enabled': False, u'channel': {u'category': u'gaming', u'status': u'5x Legend - Playing the TOP DECKS from DECK WARS to Legendary! Handlock, Miracle and Shaman. (Never played Shaman EVUR)', u'views_count': 56403101, u'subcategory': None, u'language': u'en', u'title': u'kungentv', u'screen_cap_url_huge': u'http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews/live_user_kungentv-630x473.jpg', u'producer': True, u'tags': None, u'subcategory_title': u'', u'category_title': u'', u'screen_cap_url_large': u'http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews/live_user_kungentv-320x240.jpg', u'mature': None, u'screen_cap_url_small': u'http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews/live_user_kungentv-70x53.jpg', u'screen_cap_url_medium': u'http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews/live_user_kungentv-150x113.jpg', u'timezone': u'Europe/Stockholm', u'login': u'kungentv', u'channel_url': u'http://www.justin.tv/kungentv', u'id': 30383713, u'meta_game': u'Hearthstone: Heroes of Warcraft'}, u'up_time': u'Mon May 19 00:34:43 2014', u'meta_game': u'Hearthstone: Heroes of Warcraft', u'format': u'live', u'stream_type': u'live', u'channel_count': 3671, u'abuse_reported': False, u'video_width': 1920, u'geo': u'SE', u'name': u'live_user_kungentv', u'language': u'en', u'stream_count': 0, u'video_bitrate': 3665.328125, u'broadcaster': u'obs', u'channel_view_count': 0}]
>>> result[0]['broadcast_part']
6
```

Python 2 uses ASCII to encode / decode between Unicode and byte string values as needed.

Generally speaking, you *want* your textual data as Unicode values; your program should be a Unicode sandwich. Decode your data to Unicode when you receive it, encode when you send it out again. It's just like any other serialized data; you don't work with string timestamps when you can work with `datetime` objects, you don't work with bytestrings if you try to make numeric calculations, you'd convert to `int` or `float` or `decimal.Decimal()` values instead, etc.

Comment: Amazing, did not know that. I'm curious why my post is getting down voted. What is wrong with it.

Comment: @CvR_XX: My guess is that people have grown a little impatient about Unicode questions; there are 100s of posts asking how to remove those pesky `u''` prefixes from their strings, for example.

Comment: oh yeah makes sense, the problem was that I didn't realize that the whole string was in a list. So i got error's and blamed it on Unicode.